# Chemistry.SE private beta invites

Tags: discussion

We're having a slight problem on chem.SE--we aren't getting many questions.

It was suggested on the meta that we ask Phy.SE and bio.SE for people willing to late-join the private beta. I can provide invites (I'll need your email address--alternatively you can send me a blank email on `manishearth[at]toolserver[dot] o r g`)

I don't know how useful this post will be--I guess we already got all the chem experts from Physics. But it's worth a shot :/

Comment: There was [this guy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27819/gas-chromatography-mass-spectrometry-can-i-use-peak-ratios-and-molecular-mass-t).

Comment: @dmckee: Oh, I know there already is a bunch--I referred TerryBollinger and he's been pretty active out there. Also tmac, though he's not active. I'm hoping for more.

Comment: @dmckee oh, I misread the comments and thought it was referring to a51 commitment. I offered the guy an invite, thanks!